# Add new string to product url

Tags: magento-1.9, url

I would like to ask if it's possible to make magento ignore a string added to a product url. For example, I have a product url: http://mywebsite.lc/product-name

Is it possible that when entering: http://mywebsite.lc/product-name/some-string

magento can still understand and direct to: http://mywebsite.lc/product-name while keeping the string on the url?

I need the string part for some js functions, and also for a friendly URL.

Thanks you

Comment: Hi @Bao Doan welcome to Magento SE. Can you please explain more. Like what do you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

While your can write a controller and a module to ignore the last part of the item URL you'll also need to set a session variable and check that session variable in your desired `js`.

That's an Overkill.

A simpler approach would be to use

```
http://mywebsite.lc/product-name/?custom=some-string
```

Then you can simply add js to check value of the custom url parameters

Comment: thanks for answering, yeah it can work like that. But there gonna be a param on the URL, which is not exactly user friendly